# Extract recognized date string passed to parse method in Chronic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, chronic

I'd like to mimic the functionality of the Mac calendar quick event or Fantastical's quick entry.  Using the Chronic gem, I can pass a string like:

```
"Today at 3pm"
=> 2014-01-24 15:00:00 -0600
```

Chronic parsing doesn't work if you pass in something like:

```
"Eat at Joes Today at 3pm" 
=> nil
```

What I've done so far is use a simple regex to split a string at a word normally used to return a date with Chronic.  The initial regex is simple:

```
scan(/(.+)(tomorrow{1}.+|in\s.+|next\s.+|today\s.+)/)
```

This returns an array with the "title", if you will, and the string I want to sent to Chronic to parse for me.

Two questions:

1. Is this really the best way to do this?  I'd have to provide some mega regex to split whatever string I think my users will submit here.
2. Would hacking at Chronic be better?  It's already parsing the dates for me, but my initial thought is no because if you pass `Eat at Joes Today at 3pm` to Chronic.parse, it'll return nil.  It seems it doesn't recognize the part of the string for formatting the date in it's present form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't edit Chronic. Chronic's only function is to parse natural language date time, not other input. You might be interested in the `Nickel` gem here:

https://github.com/iainbeeston/nickel

This separates time from other language.

```
n = Nickel.parse("use the force on july 1st at 9am", Time.now)
n.message                       #=> "use the force"
n.occurrences.first.start_date  #=> "20110701"
```

Comment: Holy crap!  Never heard of Nickel.  This would work perfectly.  Thank you.